# How to click on a Radio Button as per the HTML using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click on element with following html code:

```
<div class="delivery-pseudo-table">
<div class=" i-popup-lk user-address" id="userAddress">
<div class="address-container">
<div class="titlebar">
<h1 class="title"></h1>
</div>
<div id="userAddressContent"></div>
</div>
<div class="hide j-map map" id="addressMap"></div>
<div class="hide j-map-pickpoint postamat-map" id="pickpointMap"></div>
<div class="added-addres-loader"></div>
</div>
<ul class="delivery-method" data-jsv-df=""><li class="selfDelivery selectDeliveryWay active" data-jsv="#34_#35_" title="">
<script type="jsv#37_"></script>
<label><input autocomplete="off" checked="checked" data-id="2" name="orderDetails.DeliveryWay_q" type="radio" value="Self"/>Самовывоз</label>
<script type="jsv/37_"></script>
</li><li class="courierDelivery selectDeliveryWay" data-jsv="/35_#38_" title="">
<script type="jsv#39_"></script>
<label><input autocomplete="off" data-id="1" name="orderDetails.DeliveryWay_q" type="radio" value="Courier"/>Доставка курьером</label>
<script type="jsv/39_"></script>
</li><li class="wbpostamatDelivery selectDeliveryWay" data-jsv="/38_#40_" title="">
<script type="jsv#41_"></script>
<label><input autocomplete="off" data-id="16" name="orderDetails.DeliveryWay_q" type="radio" value="WbPostamat"/>Постамат</label>
<script type="jsv/41_"></script>
</li></ul>
```

I need to click on button with value "Courier"

And I am trying to do it with following Python code:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][@value='Courier']")
elem.click()
```

(I've also tried to find by xpath)

But it says that the element is invisible. Are the any ways to click on such element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this xPath:

```
//input[@type='radio' and @value='Courier']
```

also try to use `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='radio' and @value='Courier']"))).click()
```

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

`WebDriverWait` statement is for waiting at least 10 seconds until element will be clickable and only then clicks on it.

***PS:*** more information about `WebDriverWait` can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

***EDIT:*** try to execute JavaScript:

```
radio_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='Courier']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radio_btn)
```

Comment: tried but there is the same error: "Message: element not visible"

Comment: check in dev tools if with my xpath there is only one element and it is the element you need. Also check if element is in `iframe/frame`

Comment: yes, there is only one element with your xpath and there is no `frame/iframe`

Comment: check if you have not other (old browsers opened). Also I have added info in my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared the `<ul>` tag contains a lot of *JavaScripts* so to invoke `click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.delivery-method li.courierDelivery.selectDeliveryWay input[value='Courier']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='delivery-method']//li[@class='courierDelivery selectDeliveryWay']//input[@value='Courier']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: i got TimeoutException

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.